# How to put the build date of application somewhere in the application?

Tags: c#

I would like to put the date the application was built somewhere in the application. Say the about box. Any ideas how this can be done? I need to do this for C# but I am also looking for a general idea, so you can answer this for any specific language other than C#.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Typically we just go with the executable's last modify date.  This will be set when the exe is built and usually never changes (short of someone actually editing the file).  When the file is installed, copied, moved, etc, Windows doesn't change that value.

```
DateTime buildDate = 
   new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).LastWriteTime;
```

We use this technique for the about dialogs in our C# and C++ apps.

Comment: If you're working with GAC assemblies, this will return when this assembly was installed.

Comment: `FileInfo` also has a `CreationTime` property. Would that be better or worse or the same as using `LastWriteTime`?

Comment: I can answer my own question: 'LastWriteTime' is better. Basically, `CreationTime` is when the file was created and `LastWriteTime` is when the contents last changed. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10277765/1339280

Answer (score 15):

The third number of the assembly version is a julian date with 0=1 Jan 2000 if you're using [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]

e.g.

```
DateTime buildDate = new DateTime(2000,1,1).AddDays(
  System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.Build
 );
```

Comment: And, how/where exactly do you do that, practically? "*" is not allowed in the normal Assembly Information field in the project properties.

Comment: Ah, never mind. It accepts "*" as third value in the properties dialog if the last field is left empty. Thanks for this. On a related note, the fourth field (Revision) is the time stamp, but it has to be multiplied by 2 before it can be used for AddSeconds().

Answer (score 2):

You [should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52608/is-subversion-version-control-necessary-for-a-small-development-group-1-2-prog) be using version control - [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) is free. Then you could include a number from the version control system that would unambiguously identify the source code used to build the app. A date won't do that. There are other advantages too.

- Full history of all changes to the project.
- Work seamlessly with other developers on the same project.

EDIT: Nikhil is already doing all this. But [for some incomprehensible reason](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointy-Haired_Boss) he has been told to include the date as well. I'm going to leave this answer here anyway, for future readers of this question.

Comment: That's exactly what I explained, the revision number is all you need, which is exactly what we have right now. But for some reason I cannot understand, I have been told to include the exact date and time the app was built.

Comment: This is not relevant to the question but is good general advice.

Answer (score 0):

There are usually keywords in your source code control system for this sort of thing.

Otherwise, look at including the date and time in the version number, or simply creating a small source code file which contains the date and time, and gets included in the build

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio and Windows, you can use this:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%"
set "Min=%dt:~10,2%"
set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set "prj=$(ProjectName)"
set prj=%prj: =_%
echo using System; namespace %prj% { public static class Build { public static DateTime Date = new DateTime(%YYYY%, %MM%, %DD%, %HH%, %MIN%, %Sec%);}} > "$(ProjectDir)\BuildTimestamp.cs
```

then using:

```
var dt = Build.Date;
PublishDate.Text = dt.ToString("DOP: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```