# ClickOnce is modifying my file dates

Tags: deployment, clickonce

When users get a new update via ClickOnce, the file modification date for the executables and dll's are getting updated to the date of installation.   
How can I keep them at the same date as when the project was built?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104353/put-build-date-in-about-box/

Comment: The top answer on that question suggests a more reliable way to get the date from the version number, which might solve this issue?